# How can I make the labels more readable in this lollipop plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

[image: Plot image.]

I am trying to make a lollipop plot that includes a text 'condition' and a value associated. The issue I am having is that, because there is so much data, the labels overlap. Is there an easy fix for this?

This is my code (and my issue):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(file = '24 hpi MP BP.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
group <- df$Name
value <- df$Bgd.count

data <- data.frame(
     x=group,
     y=value
)

 ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y), color="skyblue") +
     geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
     theme_light() +
     coord_flip() +
     theme(
         panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
     )
```

I am hoping to get a clear separation on the labels

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: We can't see your plot to know what the exact problem is, and cannot reproduce your plot because you have not included any reproducible data. Without these, it's not clear how we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have now added the image of the lollipop plot. Hopefully you will be able to see what the issue is with the overlapping. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not provide a reproducible example, so here a more general answer.

The problem is that you want to plot hundreds of discrete values. That is bound to yield a crowded graphic.

your options:

1. reduce the labels (don’t label all axis) and show only few labels .
2. focus only on few important data points - I think this would be my preferred approach, as you also give your “story” more justice.
3. Group your values and show “aggregate values” such as means/error bars
4. Make your graph appropriately large (change the height of the so called graphic device)
5. Use facets (but this will not really help with the crowding in all cases)
6. Shorten your labels
7. Make the font smaller
8. Last, but definitely not least, change your visualisation strategy.